# TPL Dataflow - Timer Action Block

Tags: c#, async-await, tpl-dataflow

I'm new to TPL Dataflow and was looking for an action block to basically push an object on a timer - specifically to produce heartbeats on every interval.  I was unable to find anything out of the box so I decided to create a wrapper class on action block that would give me the desired functionality. I also wanted to include async/await pattern in the implementation.

Given the following heartbeat object:

```
public class Heartbeat
{
    public DateTime HearbeatTimeUtc { get; set; }
}
```

The wrapper class:

```
public class TimerActionBlock<TInput>
{
    private readonly ActionBlock<TInput> _actionBlock;

    public TimerActionBlock(Func<TInput, Task> func,
        Func<TInput, Exception, Task> excptionFunc)
    {
        _actionBlock = new ActionBlock<TInput>(async input =>
        {
            try
            {
                await func(input);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                await excptionFunc(input, e);
            }
        });
    }

    public void Start(Func<Task<TInput>> inputFunc, 
        TaskScheduler scheduler,
        TimeSpan dueTime,
        TimeSpan period,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken,
        Action<Exception> onError)
    {
        Task
            .Factory
            .StartNew(async () =>
                {
                    await Task.Delay(dueTime);

                    while (true)
                    {
                        var input = await inputFunc();

                        await _actionBlock.SendAsync(input);

                        var task = Task.Delay(period,
                            cancellationToken);

                        try
                        {
                            await task;
                        }
                        catch (TaskCanceledException)
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }, 
                cancellationToken, 
                TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, 
                scheduler)
            .ContinueWith(task => { onError(task.Exception); }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
    }
}
```

Calling code would something like the following:

```
var timerActionBlock = new TimerActionBlock<Heartbeat>(heartbeat =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(heartbeat));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
    (heartbeat, exception) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    });

timerActionBlock
    .Start(() => Task.FromResult(new Heartbeat
        {
            HearbeatTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow
        }), 
        TaskScheduler.Default, 
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), 
        TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000), 
        CancellationToken.None, 
        Console.WriteLine);
```

Comment: TPL DataFlow is about creating a data mesh and having data flow.  I'm not sure I understand the need to have an action block that just fires on a timer.  When you say you want the timer to push an object on a timer do you want this to be the source of the Data Flow?  If so then Action block isn't the correct block to base it on.  With more information I could maybe help provide an answer

Comment: You might also look at the periodic stuff in this library that I created: https://github.com/BrannonKing/Kts.ActorsLite